# How to test router and firewall setting in a small networking lab at home

Tags: linux, ping, raspberry-pi, traceroute, mikrotik-routeros

I have a small network for learning purposes at home, comprised of a couple of routers (Mikrotik) and Raspberry Pi 3s. The objective is to learn/test basic networking. What I want to do is set up some basic routing, firewalling and port-forwarding on the routers and then test that these work as intended between the Raspberry Pis (rpi's). One rpi will be the "listening" device and the other will be the "connecting" device.

What program or service could I start on the "listening" device (so that I have a target IP:port), and how can I test that a connection is possible from the "connecting" device (e.g. what utility to use)?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for how to establish a test connection, the answer is Netcat. On the server (listener):

```
$ nc -lvp 12345
```

-l means listen, -v means verbose (gives you more information), and p indicates the port (12345). Then, on the client (connector):

```
$ nc -v [server IP] 12345
```

Again the -v means verbose. Then it uses the Telnet syntax (in fact, you could also use telnet on the client) of `host port`.